# How to add jquery tabs dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-tabs

I want to jquery tabs dynamically
but there is an error on console.

Please [Visit This Link](http://jsfiddle.net/6VrwD/6/)

Comment: You're missing the leading `$` from your selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("#tabs").tabs("add" , "http://google.com" , "A newTab" , [2] );`

You are missing the leading $.